# Solving word problems involving triangles/bearings

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The sonar of a submarine detects a navy battleship that is $4000$ ft above the depth of an angle of elevation of $36$ degrees. The submarine's sonar also detects a giant squid resting on the surface directly in the path of the navy battleship at an angle of elevation of $48$ degrees. How far is the battleship from the giant squid?

For my answer I got $1,119.09$ ft but I am not positive if I am right or not. I used Law of Sines to find this answer. Can anyone tell me if I am correct or if incorrect, what the right answer is and how you got it. If I am wrong I may have drawn my diagram wrong and that could be the cause of my wrong answer. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. By using the data given, you can find out the distance between the two objects by making two right triangles with $48$ and $36$ degrees with a height of $4000$ ft. Then you use the law of sine to find the missing lengths to give you the answer of $1119.09$ ft. Thus, that concludes your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought no one would answer my question. I can't thank you enough!